# Why are booleans copyable even though the documentation doesn't indicate that?

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand the ownership and borrowing concept. At first I thought it was pretty simple once you understood it. But...

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = 5;

    let _y = double(a);
    println!("{}", a);
}

fn double(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x * 2
}
```

At first I would have expected this to not compile, because `a` would have been moved to `_y`.

I was a bit confused, but [I found out](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html#copy-types) that I would have been right except that `i32` is an exception to the rule because it implements the copy trait.

I looked at [the `Copy` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) and as I understand it, they list all types that implement this trait at the bottom.

So the `bool` type is not present and so I assumed it's default behaviour was to be "moved". But...

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = true;

    let _y = change_truth(a);
    println!("{}", a);
}

fn change_truth(x: bool) -> bool {
    !x
}
```

**Doesn't fail either.**

Now I am quite confused. I found the [`Clone` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) that seems to be closely related to the copy trait. But unless I missed it, they don't really mention it in the learning doc.

Can someone give me some more info ?

**Update:**

1. I have filed an [issue on the Rust repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25893).
2. I have also made a [pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/25898) with some change proposals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your understanding is pretty spot-on, this seems to be an issue with the docs. The documentation doesn't show `Copy` instances for any of the primitives types, even though they are definitely `Copy`. As an example to show that the compiler considers `bool` to be `Copy`, the following compiles just fine:

```
fn takes_copyable<T: Copy>(foo: T) {}

fn main() {
    takes_copyable(true);
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you! So I do understand it correctly, that is a relief! Do all the primitive types implement the copy trait ? This should definitely be mentioned in the docs since it is a crucial exception to the most important rule in the language. If you didn't already do so, I will create an issue on github to let them know :)

Comment: Yes, I believe the primitive types should all implement `Copy`. And this is definitely worth filing an issue for, so go ahead.

Comment: Great thank you for your time :) The issue has been created: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25893

Comment: Actually it does say in the documentation(the "Book") that all primitive types are copied by default instead of changing ownership.

Comment: @LilianA.Moraru Does it? I must have missed it. Can you give a link because it is not mentioned were [I would assume it to be explained](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html#copy-types).

Comment: References but not mutable references implement copy (obviously, copying &mut would violate aliasing).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. Could you elaborate or point me to some reading material? Thanks!

Comment: @MathieuDavid When I said that the primitive types should be `Copy`, I was thinking of the primitive numeric types, char and bool. I didn't include references (`&T`, which is `Copy`) and mutable references (`&mut T`, which cannot be copied).

Comment: I didn't consider references as primitive types, are they ? I guess it's just a matter of definition

Comment: @MathieuDavid Well, they're primitive types in the sense that they are types that are defined as part of the language, not in a library.

Comment: Ok, I must say that it's not an easy language to learn. Mostly due to the fact that you have to understand quite complex concepts for even the simplest programs. Making it very difficult to learn the language gradually by introducing concepts when needed because you need an awful lot of them right from the start. But despite that I kind of like Rust

Comment: @MathieuDavid I don't see where is the complex part... Also, pointers/references are not primitive types, you miss the idea(and it's not a concept introduced in Rust, it is available in any programming language). Primitive types are u8..u64, i8..i64, floats, chars, bool... I guess fjh misguided you. Primitive types are one thing and things available by default in a programming language are another thing...

Comment: Well the complexity of Rust lies in the fact that it requires of you to understand some more advanced concepts (ownership, borrowing, references, bindings, patterns, traits, ...) before you can even begin coding something simple. But once you master that though, it's easier than C and C++ in my opinion. In my experience the learning curve of C and C++ was more gradual. Anyways, it doesn't really matter. This is how I experienced learning Rust. It is not necessarily how everyone experience it.